# How to use dell smart card keyboard RT7D60 in Ubuntu

Tags: smartcard

I have Dell external usb keyboard with smart card reader builtin. I want to use it to read my eID. When I plug the keyboard in, I can use the keyboard but not the smartcard reader. How can I use the smart card reader?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older smart card readers (and eID readers) need additional drivers in order to work on Ubuntu. You can install them by typing the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libacr38u libacr38ucontrol0 libacr38ucontrol-dev
```

After installation plug in the keyboard, and it should work. Now, if you put your smart card in the reader, it should light up and smart card applications should recognize the card. You can test using Cardpeek (GUI) or the  `pcsc_scan` (commandline).

*See this question to [use the Belgian eID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571850/how-to-setup-belgian-eid-ubuntu-14-04)*

[Source (in Dutch)](http://test.eid.belgium.be/faq/faq_nl.htm)

Comment: Leaving some feedback here: this works on my dell laptop with an integrated card reader. Thank you!