# unable to install libraries (*acr28)

Tags: 16.04, apt, 17.10, libraries, synaptic

I am eventually trying setup the [belgian card reader](https://eid.belgium.be/en/linux-eid-software-installation) and I have found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571850/how-to-setup-belgian-eid-ubuntu-14-04), which worked on my previous machine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), but it is not working on my current one (Ubuntu 17.10)

When I download and

`sudo dpkg -i eid-archive_2018.1_all.deb`

I get the following message, which looks OK to me:

```
(Reading database ... 492593 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack eid-archive_2018.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking eid-archive (2018.1) over (2018.1) ...
Setting up eid-archive (2018.1) ...
Repository enabled, keys installed. Please run "apt-get update" followed by
"apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer" to install the middleware and the viewer, respectively.
```

When I then:

`apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer`

I get the following error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package eid-mw 
E: Unable to locate package eid-viewer
```

I have also noticed that I do not have the required libraries as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571850/how-to-setup-belgian-eid-ubuntu-14-04).

When I try to install them with:

`sudo apt install libacr38u libacr38ucontrol0 libacr38ucontrol-dev libccid`

I get the following error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package libacr38u
E: Unable to locate package libacr38ucontrol0
E: Unable to locate package libacr38ucontrol-dev
```

Does anyone know why I cannot install those libraries? As far as I recall, I could install them with no problem at all on my previous machine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

I also tried to install the libraries with synaptic, but I could not find them.

Comment: `16.04` is the last version with libacr*. No libacr[any-version] in 17.10 or 18.04 . Solution : Get the `16.04` packages, and install with `sudo gdebi ./[package]` ... https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libacr38&searchon=names

Comment: It does work, libraries are now installed, thanks. I get, however, the same error message (`E: Unable to locate package eid-mw` and `E: Unable to locate package eid-viewer`) when I run `sudo apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer` after `sudo apt-get update`. Any idea?

Comment: May be read this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/571850/how-to-setup-belgian-eid-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: This is the one I referred two times in my post, whose instructions I was following. I did work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but not working on my current machine (Ubuntu 17.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Belgian card reader, Ubuntu 17.10

Libraries "libacr38u" https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libacr38&searchon=names ... Download xenial packages. And `cd Downloads/ && sudo apt install ./libacr38u*`

Eid https://eid.belgium.be/en/linux-eid-software-installation Download eid-archive.deb : Todays **update = 05 Apr 2018** → `Ubuntu 17.10 artful` is now included.

When ...

```
deb http://files.eid.belgium.be/debian artful main
deb http://files2.eid.belgium.be/debian artful main
```

... is added to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the the keys `/usr/share/eid-archive/keys/` are installed ( `sudo apt-key add *` ) you can run `sudo apt update` and then install eid-viewer etc. http://files.eid.belgium.be/debian/dists/artful/main/binary-amd64/Packages  with apt.

Comment: The eID software appears to be installed, however I am getting an error when I try to read my ID card ("failed to read identity data"). I have [this smart card reader](http://www.h-mc.be/?product=lecteur-de-carte-eid-sim&lang=fr), can you see if I am missing any library or anything like that to get the card read with this smart card reader?

Comment: Probably the same as you used with Ubuntu 16.04 : Please check your "backup".